# How to add 1 billion rows in Impala?

Tags: java, cloudera, impala

I am exploring impala for POC ,my task is to add 1 billion rows and check how fast we can insert and retrieve data.
I have created a table which has 30 rows half of them are string, 2 are timestamps and rest are integers. Its taking close to 3 hours to add 1 million rows, very slow for production.

I wrote a small java code where I am inserting data in batch of 1000, the code is very slow and took almost 13 hours to just add 4 million rows.

```
    private static Connection connectViaDS() throws Exception {
        Connection connection = null;

        Class.forName("com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver");

        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);

        return connection;

    }

    private static void writeInABatchWithCompiledQuery(int records) {

        int protocol_no = 233,s_port=20,d_port=34,packet=46,volume=58,duration=39,pps=76,
                bps=65,bpp=89,i_vol=465,e_vol=345,i_pkt=5,e_pkt=54,s_i_ix=654,d_i_ix=444,_time=1000,flow=989;

        String s_city = "Mumbai",s_country = "India", s_latt = "12.165.34c", s_long = "39.56.32d",
                s_host="motadata",d_latt="29.25.43c",d_long="49.15.26c",d_city="Damouli",d_country="Nepal";

        long e_date= 1275822966, e_time= 1370517366;

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

       // int total = 1000000*1000;

        int total = 1000000*1000;

        int counter =0;

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = connectViaDS();



            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlCompiledQuery);


            Timestamp ed = new Timestamp(e_date);
            Timestamp et = new Timestamp(e_time);

            while(counter <total) {

                for (int index = 1; index <= 1000; index++) {

                    counter++;

                    preparedStatement.setString(1, "s_ip" + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(1);
                    preparedStatement.setString(2, "d_ip" + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(2);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(3, protocol_no + index);
                    //   System.out.println(3);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(4, s_port + index);
                    //  System.out.println(4);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(5, d_port + index);
                    //  System.out.println(5);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(6, packet + index);
                    //  System.out.println(6);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(7, volume + index);
                    //  System.out.println(7);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(8, duration + index);
                    //   System.out.println(8);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(9, pps + index);
                    //  System.out.println(9);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(10, bps + index);
                    //  System.out.println(10);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(11, bpp + index);
                    //   System.out.println(11);
                    preparedStatement.setString(12, s_latt + String.valueOf(index));
                    //  System.out.println(12);
                    preparedStatement.setString(13, s_long + String.valueOf(index));
                    //  System.out.println(13);
                    preparedStatement.setString(14, s_city + String.valueOf(index));
                    //  System.out.println(14);
                    preparedStatement.setString(15, s_country + String.valueOf(index));
                    //  System.out.println(15);
                    preparedStatement.setString(16, d_latt + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(16);
                    preparedStatement.setString(17, d_long + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(17);
                    preparedStatement.setString(18, d_city + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(18);
                    preparedStatement.setString(19, d_country + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(19);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(20, i_vol + index);
                    //   System.out.println(20);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(21, e_vol + index);
                    //   System.out.println(21);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(22, i_pkt + index);
                    //   System.out.println(22);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(23, e_pkt + index);
                    //   System.out.println(23);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(24, s_i_ix + index);
                    //   System.out.println(24);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(25, d_i_ix + index);
                    //    System.out.println(25);
                    preparedStatement.setString(26, s_host + String.valueOf(index));
                    //   System.out.println(26);
                    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(27, ed);
                    //   System.out.println(27);
                    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(28, et);
                    //   System.out.println(28);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(29, _time);
                    //   System.out.println(29);
                    preparedStatement.setInt(30, flow + index);
                    //   System.out.println(30);
                    // System.out.println(index);
                    preparedStatement.addBatch();

                }
                preparedStatement.executeBatch();

                preparedStatement.clearBatch();

                //System.out.println("Counter = "+counter);


            }


        //    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //    int[] inserted = preparedStatement.executeBatch();
         //   long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

           // System.out.println("total time taken to insert the batch = " + (end - start) + " ms");
            //System.out.println("total time taken = " + (end - start)/records + " s");
            //System.out.println("Inserted: "+inserted);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Data is updating at snails pace , I tried increasing the batch size but its decreasing the speed.
I don't know if my code is wrong or I need to tune Impala for better performance. Please guide.

I am using VM for testing, here is other details-

```
System.

Os - Ubuntu 16
RAM - 12 gb
Cloudera - CDH 6.2
Impala daemon limit - 2 gb
Java heap size impala daemon - 500mb
HDFS Java Heap Size of NameNode in Bytes - 500mb.
```

Please let me know if more details are required.

Comment: If you want to add that much data prior to testing then do it directly in sql or use the database import functionality

Comment: @Joakim , we already are using sql, I have been given task to check impala performance as we need to query lots of data , I heard impala works very fast so I am exploring it

Comment: I meant to execute the sql directly via the shell, not via java, for this part.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823424/7852833.  Your setup is too small for Impala.  And refer to reference architecture for Impala https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/reference-architecture.html to get a sense of what you need before attempting this.